# How to paginate an array of objects in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to render each of these objects in the array in single pages without using Context API. Using the map function shows all three objects on the same page. Is there any to dynamically show each object on different pages and allow the user to go to the next object once he is done with the current one.

```
`[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "question": "Why do you like the USA ?",
        "option_list": "{\"option1\": \"Tourist Spot\", \"option2\": \"Food\"}",
      
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "question": "How is food in the USA ?",
        "option_list": "{\"option1\": \"Good\", \"option2\": \"Bad\", \"option3\": \"No Comments\"}",
    },
   {
        "id": 3,
        "question": "Will you recommend visiting the USA ?",
        "option_list": "{\"option1\": \"Yes\", \"option2\": \"No\"}",
    },

]`
```

I want to show it like this -

Page -1                     Page -2                               Page -3
Why do you like the USA?       How is food in the USA?              Will you recommend visiting the USA?
a. Tourist Spot             a. Good                               a. Yes
b. Food                     b. Bad                                b. No
c. No Comments

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const App = () => {

const myData = 

[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "question": "Why do you like the USA ?",
        "option_list": "{\"option1\": \"Tourist Spot\", \"option2\": \"Food\"}",
      
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "question": "How is food in the USA ?",
        "option_list": "{\"option1\": \"Good\", \"option2\": \"Bad\", \"option3\": \"No Comments\"}",
    },
   {
        "id": 3,
        "question": "Will you recommend visiting the USA ?",
        "option_list": "{\"option1\": \"Yes\", \"option2\": \"No\"}",
    },

]

return(
```

```
  <>
       


        <div className="grid">
            {myData.map((post) => {

                return (
                    <div className="questionAnsContainer" style={{
                        display: 'flex',
                        backgroundColor: '#1B164E',
                        marginLeft: '50px',
                        marginRight: '50px',
                        flexDirection: 'column',
                        height: 'auto',
                        borderTopLeftRadius: '10px',
                        borderTopRightRadius: '10px',
                    }}>
                        <p
                            style={{
                                color: "#fff",
                                textAlign: "left",
                                padding: "8px",
                                fontFamily: 'Oswald',
                                fontSize: '18px',
                                width: 'auto',
                            }}
                        >
                            Q. {post.question}
                        </p>
                        <div className="options">
                            <div>
                                <form onSubmit={(e) => this.props.submit}>
                                    {
                                        Object.entries(store1).map(([key, value]) => {
                                            return (
                                                <div>
                                                    <div className="radio_container">
                                                        <label className="radio_label">
                                                            <input
                                                                type="radio"
                                                                name="radio"
                                                                onChange={handleChange}
                                                                value={value}
                                                                //id={"selected_answer" + question_id}
                                                                question_id={post.question_id}
                                                            // checked={this.props.selected_answer_list[question_id] === value ? true : false}
                                                            />
                                                            <span className="checkmark">{value}</span>
                                                        </label>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            )
                                        })
                                    }
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                );
            })}
        </div>
    </>
```

```
)



}



export default App;
```

Comment: You may maintain the current page number in state and render index matching to that page number.

Comment: Agreed with @Nik